# Homebrew, Jekyll, RVM, and usr/local

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew, jekyll

I want to set up a Jekyll blog but keep running into the same issue.

I've installed Homebrew (for using Git) as well as the dependencies that RVM needs. At present, the output of `brew doctor` says everything should be ready to go e.g, `Raring to brew`. The trouble starts when I try to install RVM itself.

I've followed the single-user instructions on the RVM site but the system chokes when I try to install ruby 1.9.3 instead of 2 (or 2.0.2, for that matter). I've installed the Ruby dependencies as well and can get `rvm is a function` but it still doesn't work.

I should mention that I've sourced RVM per the install instructions but wonder if the line I added to .bash_profile is tripping things up because the source line isn't where it's supposed to be, e.g,

.bash_profile

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"`

This is the only line in the file and exists simply to ensure that I'm getting Homebrew's version of Git rather than the system's. Does the rvm source need to be at the end? I'm quite confused.

At the same time, as a result of the above lines, Jekyll refuses to generate into its destination folder and I'm seeing errors related to the gems that jekyll installs alongside itself. Does the gem support 2.0.0 yet or should we still be using 1.9.3?

Comment: Which version of OSX are you on?

Comment: Currently running 10.7.5. My concern with all of this is comes down to what RVM will do to the $PATH, potentially moving things around and breaking a "good" Homebrew config.

Comment: If you put the `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` after the `export PATH…` line, the save the file and run `source .bash_profile` to reload it. Then do `echo $PATH` and you'll see what the result is.

Comment: it might be required to open new shell after the above steps

Comment: @iain, I took your advice and tried it again and rvm seems to be working now, however I still get Liquid errors when trying to run Jekyll

Comment: Are you able to add them as an edit to your question?

Comment: I posted the error on a GitHub [thread](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/844) as I didn't have room to show the entire thing.

Comment: I've tried using rbenv as well and it still won't generate, I added the error message to the original GH thread.

Comment: @Chris glad you got it fixed in the end.

Comment: If the fixed on the GH thread worked, want to copy the answer over here and Accept it so we can close the question and have it around on SO for future reference?

Comment: @AndrewJanke, it turned out to be an error on my part, I had a malformed Liquid tag in one of my templates that was tripping things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, the GitHub thread with the tag example is [here](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/844).